# How can I apply a function one column at a time?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy datastructure as follows:

```
[[['diaad'],
  ['iaadf'],
  ['aadfe'],
  ['hedbb'],
  ['edbbb'],
  ['dbbbb']],

 [['gegec'],
  ['ehecf'],
  ['gecfc'],
  ['gadff'],
  ['adfef'],
  ['dffgc']],

 [['ddddj'],
  ['dddjd'],
  ['ddjdd'],
  ['jfffd'],
  ['fgfdb'],
  ['ggdbb']]]
```

which is instantiated like this:

```
>>> a = np.array([[['diaad'], ['iaadf'],  ['aadfe'],  ['hedbb'],  ['edbbb'],  ['dbbbb']], [['gegec'],  ['ehecf'],  ['gecfc'],  ['gadff'],  ['adfef'],  ['dffgc']], [['ddddj'],  ['dddjd'],  ['ddjdd'],  ['jfffd'],  ['fgfdb'],  ['ggdbb']]])
```

Is there a direct `numpy` way of computing a custom function over pairwise elements?

For instance, say, my custom function is called `processPair(a,b)`. It should compute the result for all pairwise elements along the column i.e. between `('diaad', 'gegec')`, `('gegec', 'ddddj')` and `('diaad', 'ddddj')`. Any suggestions on doing this? I was thinking the `map` function can achieve this but am not entirely sure how though.

Comment: I would suggest using Pandas DataFrame that makes applying custom functions easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my solution. I'm not entirely pleased with it -- I feel like it should be possible to do it more elegantly -- but it works:

```
from itertools import combinations

def apply_pairwise(func, a):
    "For each row, call func with every possible combination of two values"

    stack = []
    for col_a, col_b in combinations(range(a.shape[0]), 2):
        stack.append(np.hstack([a[col_a], a[col_b]]))

    combined = np.vstack(stack)

    def unpack_row(row):
        "Calls func with the values of a given numpy array as arguments"
        return func(*row.tolist())

    return np.apply_along_axis(unpack_row, 1, combined)
```

Use like this (assuming your example array `a` has been defined):

```
>>> f = lambda x, y: x + y
>>> print apply_pairwise(f, a)
['diaadgegec' 'iaadfehecf' 'aadfegecfc' 'hedbbgadff' 'edbbbadfef'
'dbbbbdffgc' 'diaadddddj' 'iaadfdddjd' 'aadfeddjdd' 'hedbbjfffd'
'edbbbfgfdb' 'dbbbbggdbb' 'gegecddddj' 'ehecfdddjd' 'gecfcddjdd'
'gadffjfffd' 'adfeffgfdb' 'dffgcggdbb']
```